# HoloEverywhere TimePickerDialog round instead of square with two columns?

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I am using example from HoloEveryWhere TimePickerDialog

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

import org.holoeverywhere.widget.Toast;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.datetimepicker.time.RadialPickerLayout;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.datetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog;

    public class PickersTimePickerFragment extends TimePickerDialog implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            initialize(this, 23, 45, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Toast.makeText(getSupportActivity(), String.format("Set time: %1$d:%2$d", hourOfDay, minute), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

But when I try use it I get wrong time picker.

In HoloEverywhere TimePickerDialog shows ok, but in my app it's this round annoying picker...

[image]

What should I do more? I need this holo normal time picker with two columns..

Answer (score 0):

Old-style date/time pickers has been removed from library.  You can use a 3rd-party backports, e.g. android-timepicker by Simon.

Comment: ok but why holoeverywhere downloaded from market shows old style time picker?

Comment: It's very old version. New version willn't publish to play store anymore. Latest version of demo you can download from main library page.